# How to make the default engine to be innodb in MySQL?(BATCH)

Tags: mysql

I need to create dozens of tables,and I need them to be `innodb`,

is there an way to do this instead of appending `engine=innodb` to each of the `create table` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default engine can be specified at the server level, using this in your `my.cnf` file :

```
set-variable    = default-storage-engine=INNODB
```

But note it'll impact all table creations on that server, if they don't specify another engine.

You can also specify the default engine for your current MySQL session, using :

```
SET storage_engine=INNODB;
```

For more informations, you can take a look at this section of the MySQL manual : [13.3. Setting the Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html)